# How do I select a line on OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

I am editing text. A cumbersome way to select a line would be to go to the beginning of the line (cmd <-) and then select the whole line to the end (Shift cmd ->). Can I do better?

Also shortcuts for cutting the line and storing it in a buffer would be welcomed. (cmd D) does not store the line in a buffer.

Comment: What program are you editing text in?

Comment: Mostly in Eclipse in then terminal, but I was hoping to get a general solution for every application if possible.

Comment: on a ful keyboard in os x home then shift-end will select the whole line, but you probably don't have a full keyboard. Also in most apps positioning the cursor at the start of the line then holding shift pressing the down arrow works.

Answer (score 12):

I always use the following:

- `cmd - Left arrow` to get to the beginning of the line
- `shift + cmd + right arrow` to mark the line
- `cmd - C` (or `cmd - X`) to copy (or cut) the marked line into the clipboard

Then I can go wherever I like and paste the line with `cmd - v`.

But as the MacOS is strongly fixed to a Graphical UserInterface using it without a mouse is possible but sometimes - like in your case - involves one keypress more than one would like.

Comment: Almost right: shift + cmd - right arrow to mark the line, NOT shift + cmd - down arrow.

Comment: shift + cmd + down arrow marks the current line icluding the newline char, shift + cmd + right arrow marks the line excluding the newline char. So we're both right ;)

Comment: The question asks for a better alternative to the cumbersome command + left-arrow then shift + command + right-arrow. How is it a good answer to use exactly that? PS, heiglandreas, I don't know for 2015 you, but in 2022, shift + command + down-arrow marks to the end of the document, not line.

Answer (score 6):

Most apps (Terminal, TextEdit, Safari's URL/search bar, etc) that accept text input honor standard key bindings (not sure what standard... ANSI, ASCII?) that include

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>: **beginning of line**

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>: **end of line**

So, <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a or e</kbd> to select a line depending on your position.

Also:

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>: **kill to end-of-line**

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd>: **yank (from buffer)**

A complete list can be generated with the `bindkey` command in Terminal, though not all of them work across all apps.

Comment: OS X text views don't use readline, they just happen to support many of the same keybindings as readline in emacs mode. C-u, C-@, and C-w shouldn't work in vanilla text views by default, even though you can define them in DefaultKeyBinding.dict.

Comment: I tested everything, before posting...  except I did it at a command prompt. doh.

Comment: This is nice but I'm still looking for something that works globally.

Answer (score 3):

You can create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "~l" = selectParagraph:;
    "~z" = (selectParagraph:, delete:);
    "~x" = (selectParagraph:, cut:);
    "~c" = (selectParagraph:, copy:);
}
```

After reopening applications, for example ⌥L should select a line in most native text views. It doesn't work in Eclipse, Terminal, or Xcode though. For more information, see the [Cocoa Text System](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html) article or [my website](http://lri.me/keybindings.html).

Another option is to use KeyRemap4MacBook and save something like this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>test</identifier>
<not>TERMINAL</not>
<not>EMACS</not>
<not>VIRTUALMACHINE</not>
<not>ECLIPSE</not>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::L, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::E, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
</item>
<item>
<name>test2</name>
<identifier>test2</identifier>
<only>ECLIPSE</only>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::L, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

In most applications ⌃A moves to the start of an unwrapped line and ⌘← moves to the start of a wrapped line, but ⌃A doesn't seem to work in Eclipse.

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Answer (score 2):

I found [a solution](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/) that seems to be working across all Cocoa apps: **have the <kbd>home</kbd> & <kbd>end</kbd> keys behave like non-Apple machines** (go to the beginning/end of a line instead of an entire document).

A file `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` needs to contain the following:

```
{
    /* home */
    "\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";
    "$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:";

    /* end */
    "\UF72B"  = "moveToEndOfLine:";
    "$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:";
}
```

If the file or directory doesn't exist, copy the above code snippet to your...pasteboard, open **Terminal** and enter these two commands:

```
mkdir ~/Library/KeyBindings
pbpaste > ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```

Restarting the app may be required for it to behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that nobody mentioned this one

Shift + CMD + left arrow (or right arrow if you are at the beginning)

Comment: No, @heiglandreas mentioned (not explicitely, but he did) it in his answer. See the second bullet.

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantages of macOS over(WIN/Linux) is the global emacs style keybindings in *almost* every text box(an exception is Microsoft Office for Mac which redefine those keybindings annoyingly...)

Regarding to this question, I always use `C-a` to reach head of line, `C-S-e` to select until end of line, then 'CMD-c` to copy the.

If you happen to have a line (which end with a \n) that crosses many literal line, I would normally do the following:

1) `C-a` to go to start of the line

2) `C-n` to go the the start of the next literal line

3) `C-b` to go back one character

4) `C-S-a` to select until head of line

5) `CMD-c` to copy the content

Might be a complex solution, but should work in most text boxes in macOS.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>

(type **aef** while holding Control and Shift)

This gives the same result as triple-clicking the current line.

Note this includes the trailing EOL in the selection. If that's not what you want, leave out the **f**.

As a bonus, after **f**, press **n** repeatedly to select multiple lines.

Tested in Xcode and TextEdit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by a "line". In TextEdit for example, long lines are automatically soft-wrapped inside the window.

To select the part of a long line where it's wrapped to a single row:
Hold shift + command, press left-arrow then right-arrow.

To select an entire line, between line breaks (aka a paragraph):

- If the cursor is at the end of the line:

  1. Optionally, to include the newline at the end of the line, press right-arrow.
  2. Press shift + option + up-arrow.
- Otherwise:

  1. If the cursor is in the middle of the line, press shift + option + up-arrow.
  2. Press shift + option + down-arrow.
  3. Optionally, press shift + option + down-arrow again to include the newline, if the following line is blank. If not (or even if so), release option and press right-arrow.